# Cumulative total count after each week passes for a given date range

Tags: sql, cumulative-sum

I have a dataset that indicates whether medical patients received a certain procedure on their visit date within the year 2020. It looks something like this:

| PatientID | Visit Date | Procedure Ind |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 01/01/2020 | 0 |
| 23456 | 04/15/2020 | 1 |
| 34567 | 07/27/2020 | 1 |

etc.

I want to create output that shows how many cumulative patients have had this procedure as of each consecutive week. In other words, in the first week of the year (1/1/2020 - 1/7/2020), x number of patients had the procedure. Then, as of the second week of the year (1/8/2020 - 1/14/2020), y number of *cumulative* patients have had the procedure (so first week + second week), and so on. It would look something like this:

| Week 1 Total (1/1/2020 - 1/7/202) | Week 2 Total (1/1/2020 - 1/14/2020) | Week 3 Total (1/1/2020 - 1/21/2020) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 20 | 25 |

I've been trying to do this for a couple of days but have hit a wall. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!!

Comment: Which databse are you using, sql server, mysql, postgre, oracle?

Answer (score 0):

would something like this help?

```
SELECT t.date, MAX(t.commulative_count) as commulative_count FROM (
SELECT 
       Concat(DATEADD(DAY,1-DATEPART(WEEK, Visit_date),Visit_date), '-' ,DATEADD(DAY,7-DATEPART(WEEK, Visit_date),Visit_date)) as date,
       SUM(Procedure_Ind) OVER (ORDER BY Visit_date) as commulative_count
FROM tableA
)t
GROUP BY t.date
```

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=061895ba426921b1c7352f4bbab35b2f)